# Curl, twitter oauth problem

Tags: curl, twitter, oauth

Does anyone see a problem with the following Curl call / how the Oauth request is built?

(i am trying to get a correctly setup request so i can finish my app) 
So i am calling the following CURL call:

```
C:\>curl -v -k --data-urlencode "status=Testing2" -H "Authorization: OAuth realm='', oauth_nonce=1276107867blah, oauth_timestamp=1276107867, oauth_consumer_key=yJDLH7BDdVi1OKIINSV7Q, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_version=1.0, oauth_signature=NWU4MDdlNjk0OGIxYWQ1YTkyNmU5YjU1NGYyOTczMmU5ZDg5
```

YWNkNA==, staus=Testing2 " http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=Testing2

and i recieve this:

```
* About to connect() to twitter.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 168.143.162.68... connected
* Connected to twitter.com (168.143.162.68) port 80 (#0)
> POST /statuses/update.xml?status=Testing2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.20.1 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.20.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8n zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.5
> Host: twitter.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: OAuth realm='', oauth_nonce=1276106370blah, oauth_timestamp=1276106370, oauth_consumer_key=yJDLH7BDdVi1OKIINSV7Q, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_version=1.0, oauth_signature=MjQzNDA1MGU4NGRmMWVjMzUwZmQ4YzE5NzMzY2I1ZDJlOTRkNmQ2Zg==, staus=Testing2
> Content-Length: 15
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:00:22 GMT
< Server: hi
< Status: 401 Unauthorized
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Twitter API"
< X-Runtime: 0.00548
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 164
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=1800
< Set-Cookie: k=209.234.229.21.1276106420885412; path=/; expires=Wed, 16-Jun-10 18:00:20 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
< Set-Cookie: guest_id=127610642214871948; path=/; expires=Fri, 09 Jul 2010 18:00:22 GMT
< Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCIm33h0pAToHaWQiJTkyMjllODE0NTdiYWE1%250AMWU1MzBmNjgwMTFiMDhkYjdlIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--8ebb3c62d461d28f8fda7b8adab642af66969f7e; domain=.twitter.com; path=/
< Expires: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:30:20 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: close
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <request>/statuses/update.xml?status=Testing2</request>
  <error>Could not authenticate with OAuth.</error>
</hash>
* Closing connection #0
```

my Parameters are setup like so:

```
var parameters = [encodeURIComponent("status="+status),encodeURIComponent("oauth_token="+ac_token),encodeURIComponent("oauth_consumer_key="+"yJDLH7BDdVi1OKIINSV7Q"),encodeURIComponent("oauth_nonce="+nonce,"oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"),encodeURIComponent("oauth_timestamp="+timestamp),encodeURIComponent("oauth_version=1.0")]

var join = parameters.join("&");
var eparamjoin =encodeURIComponent(join);
```

The key is like so:

```
var key=con_secret+"&"+ac_secret;
```

Signature base string is:

```
var signaturebs = "POST&"+encodeURIComponent(url)+"&"+eparamjoin;
```

giving this:

```
POST&http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.xml&status%253DTesting2%26oauth_token%253D142715285-yi2ch324S3zfyKyJby6WDUZOhCsiQuKNUtc3nAGe%26oauth_consumer_key%253DyJDLH7BDdVi1OKIINSV7Q%26oauth_nonce%253D1276107867blah%26oauth_timestamp%253D1276107867%26oauth_version%253D1.0
```

and signature built like so:

```
var hmac = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA1, signaturebs,key );

var signature=Base64.encode(hmac);
```

making the signature:

```
NWU4MDdlNjk0OGIxYWQ1YTkyNmU5YjU1NGYyOTczMmU5ZDg5YWNkNA==
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be as simple as a URL issue.

You're calling: http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=Testing2

The API docs suggest: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status=Testing2

They implemented the new URL path some time ago, but I don't know when or if they turned off the old one.

Comment: Thanks yeah it was a few things, the url, and also my header wanted to put Version in the second parameter instead of last oauth. It is finally working! the forums are free of my issue on this Thank you